# Merging Multiple ResultSet into Single ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

Let say I have multiple ResultSet(each resultSet would refer to 1 row in database) (they are of same table.) . Now I want to create consolidated ResultSet which would intern have all other resultSet. So my primary goal is to create a combined ResultSet which would point to all rows which where previously pointed by individual resultSet.

I am using Java. Do any one know how pragmatically we can achieve this?

Edit : we are using `java.sql.ResultSet`.

Edit : To make it more clear :

Let say I have

```
List<ResultSet> someResults ; // each resultSet Would point to a single row in database.
```

I want to create a consolidated `ResultSet finalResults;`

psudo code :

```
List<ResultSet> resultSets = // poppulated from code
ResultSet rs  = convert(resultSets) // psude conver method
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a java.sql.ResultSet, it's not possible as far as I know. I suggest you change your query instead.

Or you can retrieve the results into an java object and then combine all the objects into a Collection.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way

```
class GatheringResultSet implements ResultSet {
    List<E> resultSets;
    ResultSet current;

    GatheringResultSet(List resultSets) {
        this.resultSets = new ArrayList(resultSets);
        current = resultSets.remove(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
        if (current.next()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (resultSets.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        current = resultSets.remove(0);
        return true;
    }
```

...

the rest of the methods just delegate call to current ResultSet

Answer (score 1):

If the results are gonna be from the same table, why not use `UNION/UNION ALL`(depending on your needs) in your query itself.

Something like this:

```
select A, B
from C where Q = R
union
select A, B
from C where P = S
```

Or else, there is the hard way of iterating through each result set and populating POJOs and adding them to a `List/Set`(Based on your needs). This seems to be an overkill if there are a lot of result sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ResultSets {
        private java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets;

        private java.sql.ResultSet current;

        @lombok.SneakyThrows
        public ResultSets(java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets) {
            this.resultSets = new java.util.ArrayList<>(resultSets);
            current = resultSets.remove(0);
        }
        @lombok.SneakyThrows
        public boolean next() {
            if (current.next()) {
                return true;
            }else if (!resultSets.isEmpty()) {
                current = resultSets.remove(0);
                return next();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @lombok.SneakyThrows
        public int getInt(int pos){
            return current.getInt(pos);
        }

        @lombok.SneakyThrows
        public String getString(String field){
            return current.getString(field);
        }
    }
```

Usage :-

```
  @lombok.SneakyThrows
  public static void main(String ... args) {

        Connection conn =  pe.getConnection("backup");
        String sql1 = "SELECT count(distinct(User_Key)) FROM user_table";
        String sql2 = "SELECT count(distinct(Username)) FROM user_table";

        Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();

        List<ResultSet> resultSets = new ArrayList<>();
        resultSets.add(stmt1.executeQuery(sql1));
        resultSets.add(stmt2.executeQuery(sql2));

        ResultSets rs = new ResultSets(resultSets);

        while(rs.next()){
           System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

        }
  }
```