# java ResultSet in a while loop doesnt work for some reason

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop, resultset

im trying to make a TableView named Overeenkomst that is has a ID and 2 other ID from 2 different tables called Gevonden and Vermiste.

the gimmick is that, once the ID Overeenkomst is called on, that it checks what the other 2 ID's are, checks the values from those 2 tables Gevonden and Vermiste from the other tables and sends those values back into the javafile and eventually a FXML file.

im trying to do this with make a ResultSet inside a while loop with the thought that it will loop the right ID value from the other table but it only works once. after that one time it stops.

**Start.java**

```
private void writeTableData() {
    Database database = new Database(
        "database",
        "localhost:3306",
        "root",
        " "
    );

    try {
        ResultSet resultOvereenkomst = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testDatabase.Overeenkomst WHERE Gesloten = 1;");
        ResultSet resultGevonden = database.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM testDatabase.Gevonden");




        while (resultOvereenkomst.next() && resultGevonden.next()) {
            Bagage bagage = new Bagage();
            bagage.setId(resultOvereenkomst.getInt("OvereenkomstID"));
            bagage.setDatum(resultOvereenkomst.getString("Datum"));

            ResultSet checkGevonden = database.executeQuery("SELECT Labelnummer, BagageType FROM testDatabase.Gevonden WHERE idGevonden = " + resultOvereenkomst.getInt("GevondenID") + ";" );

            bagage.setLabelNummer(checkGevonden.getInt("Labelnummer"));
            bagage.setBagageType(checkGevonden.getString("BagageType")); 
            geslotenData.add(bagage);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }

}
```

**Bagage.java**

```
public class Bagage extends Gebruiker{

private final SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleIntegerProperty gevondenID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleIntegerProperty vermistID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty datum = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleIntegerProperty labelNummer = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleIntegerProperty vluchtNr = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty bagageType = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty tijd = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty luchthaven = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty bestemming = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty merk = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty kleur = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final SimpleStringProperty BijzondereKenmerken = new SimpleStringProperty();

//Setters
public void setId(int id){
    this.id.set(id);
}
public void setDatum(String datum){
    this.datum.set(datum);
}
public void setLabelNummer(int labelNummer){
    this.labelNummer.set(labelNummer);
}
public void setVluchtNr(int vluchtNr){
    this.vluchtNr.set(vluchtNr);
}
public void setBagageType(String bagageType){
    this.bagageType.set(bagageType);
}
public void setTijd(String tijd){
    this.tijd.set(tijd);
}
public void setLuchthaven(String luchthaven){
    this.luchthaven.set(luchthaven);
}
public void setBestemming(String bestemming){
    this.bestemming.set(bestemming);
}
public void setMerk(String merk){
    this.merk.set(merk);
}
public void setKleur(String kleur){
    this.kleur.set(kleur);
}
public void setBijzondereKenmerken(String bijzondereKenmerken){
    this.BijzondereKenmerken.set(bijzondereKenmerken);
}
public void setGevondenID(int gevondenID){
    this.gevondenID.set(gevondenID);
}
public void setVermistID(int vermistID){
    this.vermistID.set(vermistID);
}

//Getters
public Integer getId(){
    return id.get();
}
public String getDatum(){
    return datum.get();
}
public Integer getLabelNummer(){
    return labelNummer.get();
}
public Integer getVluchtNr(){
    return vluchtNr.get();
}
public String getBagageType(){
    return bagageType.get();
}
public String getTijd(){
    return tijd.get();
}
public String getLuchthaven(){
    return luchthaven.get();
}
public String getBestemming(){
    return bestemming.get();
}
public String getMerk(){
    return merk.get();
}
public String getKleur(){
    return kleur.get();
}
public String getBijzondereKenmerken(){
    return BijzondereKenmerken.get();
}
public Integer getVermistID(){
    return vermistID.get();
}
public Integer getGevondenID(){
    return gevondenID.get();
}

}
```

if i remove this piece of code:

```
ResultSet checkGevonden = database.executeQuery("SELECT Labelnummer, BagageType FROM testDatabase.Gevonden WHERE idGevonden = " + resultOvereenkomst.getInt("GevondenID") + ";" );
```

and change these two into:

```
bagage.setLabelNummer(resultGevonden.getInt("Labelnummer"));
bagage.setBagageType(resultGevonden.getString("BagageType"));
```

Then it just works. but the problem is that they dont show the right values.

I looked awhile on Stackoverflow and havent found the answer i was looking for so i hope you guys could help me.

thanks for helping in advance

Comment: you need to learn about JOINs

Comment: Your problem is, you tried to read the resultset `checkGevonden` without calling `next()` first, so you are before the first row. But JOIN is definitly the answer here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Multiple ResultSet into Single ResultSet in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436806/merging-multiple-resultset-into-single-resultset-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment from e4c5 says, you should use join to link your tables, something like :

```
private void writeTableData() {
Database database = new Database(
    "database",
    "localhost:3306",
    "root",
    " "
);

try {
    ResultSet resultOvereenkomst = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testDatabase.Overeenkomst LEFT JOIN testDatabase.Gevonden ON Gevonden.idGevonden = Overeenkomst.GevondenID  WHERE Gesloten = 1;");

    while (resultOvereenkomst.next()) {
        Bagage bagage = new Bagage();
        bagage.setId(resultOvereenkomst.getInt("OvereenkomstID"));
        bagage.setDatum(resultOvereenkomst.getString("Datum"));
        bagage.setLabelNummer(checkGevonden.getInt("Labelnummer"));
        bagage.setBagageType(checkGevonden.getString("BagageType")); 
        geslotenData.add(bagage);
    }

} catch (SQLException ex) {

}
}
```

For more informations on joins : http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: Thanks! im still learning about sql so i couldnt figure this out.